# The Source is different when the module is build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 . I have one class library "CoreModel" project and one ASP.NET project "WebBillProject".I made few changes in class library project then Run the project in Debug Mode Now i am facing this error.

[image]

I have already tried to solve it by deleting the Dll of Class Library Project form references  of "WebBillProject"  project and then Build the Class Library Project and again added the Dll to reference but the result is same.

If i click Yes then  the debugger does not counter the break points on where i made changes.

Comment: Try to delete your 'bin/debug' folder then rebuild

Comment: It Didn't work. @har07

Comment: Are those the only projects in the solution?

Comment: there is 1 more Helper LibraryProject for conversion @JonyAdamit

Comment: Open up the solution properties and click Project Dependencies. In the combobox, go over each project and see what it depends on. See if something wrong jumps in your eyes.

Comment: Also, do you have any post build events?

Comment: @JonyAdamit i found this in debug sorce file  & my solution in E:\   DRIVE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\atlmfc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\crt

Comment: @JonyAdamit  No i dnt have any post build events

Comment: Rebuild and look at the output window. Watch carefully at what it does and why. Also, when I run out of ideas, sometimes restarting visual studio surprisingly fixes many obscure issues.

Comment: Thnx all @JonyAdamit    i found this solution  project properties  --> build -- > output path  change to bin\  i case your dll is in bin if your dll is in bin\debug change  to bin\debug then 
. clean individual project --> build individual project--> build whole project